# Chaining custom querysets inside the Queryset Object to obtain a different custom queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following code:

```
class MQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

        def active(self):
            return self.filter(is_active=True)

        def type_a(self):
            return self.filter(type=AB)

        def active_type_a(self):
            return self.active().self.type_a()
```

The issues is in chaining in `active_type_a` method, because my example will fail.

Off course the above example is simple, and I can add the `filter`, but I have also more complex querysets, where I want to do this.

Comment: Should be the same way [chaining filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters) normally works. `self.active().type_a()` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the same as [chaining filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters) works outside the class.

```
def active_type_a(self):
    return self.active().type_a()
```